# MySQL query too slow about 25 seconds

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a MySQL query and it takes about 25 sec. There are not many rows (just about 200) but I don't understand why it takes long time.

Query:

```
SELECT *
     , c.id c_id
  FROM campaign c 
  JOIN campaign_category cc 
    ON c.campaign_type = cc.id
 WHERE c.is_deleted = 0
   AND c.status = 1
   AND c.id NOT IN (SELECT campaign_id FROM user_reviews WHERE user_id = 4)
   AND c.amt_req > (SELECT COUNT(id) 
                      FROM reserved_reviews 
                     WHERE camping_id = c.id 
                       AND user_id != 4) 
                 + (SELECT COUNT(id) 
                      FROM user_reviews 
                     WHERE campaign_id = c.id)
```

Edit:
 I tried with JOIN like this but i got no result:

> ```
> SELECT 
>   *, `c`.`id` as `c_id`,COUNT(`ur`.`id`) as `total_reviewed`, COUNT(`rr`.`id`) as `total_reserved`
> FROM 
> `campaign` `c`
> JOIN `campaign_category` `cc` ON `c`.`campaign_type`=`cc`.`id`
> JOIN `user_reviews` `ur` ON `ur`.`campaign_id`=`c`.`id`
> JOIN `reserved_reviews` `rr` ON `rr`.`camping_id`=`c`.`id`
> WHERE 
>      `c`.`is_deleted` =0
> AND 
>       `c`.`status` = 1
> AND 
>        `ur`.`user_id` != 4 
> GROUP BY `c`.`id`
> HAVING `c`.`amt_req` > COUNT(`ur`.`id`) + COUNT(`rr`.`id`)
> ```

Edit: Table structures: First Image - user_reviews Table, Second image campagin Table, Third image: reserved_reviews Table.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbdcz.png

Comment: Show your table structures, together with any indexes, and the result of an EXPLAIN against the query

Comment: Don't use '*' rather type the name of fields that you want to fetch.

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but if you're running wamp..then use `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost. Worked for me once.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: while i read your question **there is nothing to do with joins**

Comment: Try to remove sub queries/dependent sub queries and instead use joins

Comment: I tried with JOIN and edited post.

Comment: add your **SQL table structure**

Comment: Added Table structure thank you for your helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve this query with indexes;

```
SELECT *, c.id c_id
FROM campaign c JOIN
     campaign_category cc 
     ON c.campaign_type = cc.id
WHERE c.is_deleted = 0 AND
      c.status = 1 AND
      c.id NOT IN (SELECT campaign_id FROM user_reviews WHERE user_id = 4)
      c.amt_req > (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                   FROM reserved_reviews 
                   WHERE campaign_id = c.id AND user_id <> 4)
                  ) +
                  (SELECT COUNT(id) 
                   FROM user_reviews 
                   WHERE campaign_id = c.id
                  ) ;
```

For the outer query and joins:  `campaign(status, is_deleted, id, amt_req)` and `campaign_category(id)` (you should have the latter if it is defined as a primary key.

Then:  `user_reviews(user_id, campaign_id)`, `reserved_reviews(campaign_id, user_id)`, and `user_reviews(campaign_id)`.